# retrieving the script name in sbcl

Tags: sbcl

Suppose I have a file named '1.sb' with this content:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script

(prin1 sb-ext:*posix-argv*) (terpri)
```

If I invoke it as '1.sb a b c' I get this output:

```
("/usr/local/bin/sbcl" "a" "b" "c")
```

How do I get the name of the script file itself ('1.sb')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for sbcl, a correct (at least as far as I can tell) lightweight solution would be as in this script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script

(prin1 (apply #'concatenate 'string
         (remove-if #'null
           (list (pathname-name *load-truename*)
                 (when (pathname-type *load-truename*)
                   ".")
                 (pathname-type *load-truename*))))) (terpri)
```

Thanks to user tobik at [the Freebsd forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/62263/) for pointing me to *load-truename*.